# Save multiple fields with same name in database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to save the table having multiple rows that is generated dynamically when i try to save a data only first letter is saved in database. and when i try to save the next row it says 500 error in console. i want to save all the data of all the rows one by one in a database how can i achieve this?

Here is my code :

```
 <!--    <form action="" method="POST">  -->
                    <?php $data = array(
                        'id'=>'inventory_form', 
                        ); ?>
                    <?php  echo form_open('main/store',$data); ?>
                   <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="inv_tbl">
                            <thead>
                                <th>No</th>
                                <th>~</th>
                                <th>Barcode</th>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>SM</th>
                                <th>SPL</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Discount</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary add_inv_row"></th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="detail">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="till_check" class="is_checked" name="till_check[]" value="Bike"></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <select name="barcode[]" id="barcode" class="form-control selectpicker barcode" data-live-search="true">
                                        <option value="">Please select a barcode</option>
                                        <?php  foreach($barcodes as $barcode) :?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $barcode->barcode; ?>"><?php echo $barcode->barcode; ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="brcode_product" class="form-control productname" name="productname[]"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="sm[]" id="sm" class="form-control selectpicker sm" data-live-search="true">
                                        <option value="">Please select a Employee code</option>
                                        <?php  foreach($employee_codes as $employee_code) :?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $employee_code->emp_code; ?>"><?php echo $employee_code->emp_code; ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="spl" class="form-control spl" name="spl[]"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="price" class="form-control price" name="price[]"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="discount" class="form-control discount" name="discount[]"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="amount" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]"></td>
                                    <td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a></td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>

                                <th class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-success" id="save_btn" type="submit" name="sale_submit_btn">Save</button></th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;" class="total">0<b></b></th>

                            </tfoot>

                        </table>




                    </div> 
                   


                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                    <!--</form>-->
```

My Javascript code :-

```
function total() {
    var t = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function (i, e) {
        var amt = $(this).val() - 0;
        t += amt;
    });
    $('.total').html(t);
}

function addnewrow() {
    var n = ($('.detail tr').length - 0) + 1;

    var tr = '<tr>' +
        '<td class="no">' + n + '</td>' +
        '<td><input type="checkbox" class="till_check" name="till_check[' + till_check_counter + ']" id="till_check[' + till_check_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><select class="form-control barcode selectpicker  dyselect_' + product_barcode_counter + '" data-live-search="true" name="barcode[' + product_barcode_counter + ']" id="barcode[' + product_barcode_counter + ']">' + '<option>Please select a bar code</option>' + '</select></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control prdctn_' + product_name_counter + ' productname"  id="brcode_product['+product_name_counter+']"  name="productname[' + product_name_counter + ']" id="productname[' + product_name_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><select class="form-control selectpicker dysm_' + sm_counter + ' sm " data-live-search="true" name="sm[' + sm_counter + ']" id="sm[' + sm_counter + ']">' + '<option>Please select a Employee code</option>' + '</select></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control spl" name="spl[' + spl_counter + ']" id="spl[' + spl_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[' + product_quantity_counter + ']" id="quantity[' + product_quantity_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[' + product_price_counter + ']" id="price[' + product_price_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control discount" name="discount[' + product_discount_counter + ']" id="discount[' + product_discount_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[' + product_amount_counter + ']" id="amount[' + product_amount_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $('.detail').append(tr);
    
    
    
    
   


    //incrementing the counter
    ++product_barcode_counter;
    ++till_check_counter;
    ++product_name_counter;
    ++product_quantity_counter;
    ++sm_counter;
    ++spl_counter;
    ++product_price_counter;
    ++product_discount_counter;
    ++product_amount_counter;

    //setting the validation rules for every product attribute by calling the function 
    createValidation();
    get_barcodes();
    get_employee_codes();
  
    

    



}

    $('#save_btn').on('click', function () {
        var barcode = $('#barcode  option:selected').val();
        var productname = $('#brcode_product').val();
        var sm = $('#sm  option:selected').val();
        var spl = $('#spl').val();
        var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
        var price = $('#price').val();
        var discount = $('#discount').val();
        var amount = $('#amount').val();


        var dataString = 'barcode=' + barcode + '&productname=' + productname + '&sm=' + sm + '&spl=' + spl + '&quantity' + quantity + '&price=' + price + '&discount=' + discount + '&amount=' + amount;
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/retail/main/store",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            /*barcode: barcode,
            productname: productname,
            sm: sm,
            spl: spl,
            quantity: quantity,
            price: price,
            discount: discount,
            amount: amount*/
            data:$('#inventory_form').serialize()
        },
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        }

    });
```

Here is my Conroller code :

```
public function store(){

  
          
            /* echo ($_POST['barcode']);
             echo "<br/>";
             echo ($_POST['productname']);
             echo "<br/>";
             echo ($_POST['smsm']);
             echo "<br/>";
             echo ($_POST['spl']);
             echo "<br/>";
             echo ($_POST['quantity']);
             echo "<br/>";
             echo ($_POST['price']);
             echo "<br/>";
             echo ($_POST['discount']);
             echo "<br/>";
             echo ($_POST['amount']);
             echo "<br/>";*/
        
        
        //echo $this->input->post('barcode');
          
          
      
          
     

    if ($this->session->userdata('status')== 1) {
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['productname']); $i++) {

         $order_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
         $product_name = $this->input->post('productname')[$i];
         $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode')[$i];
         $spl= $this->input->post('spl')[$i];
         $sm= $this->input->post('sm')[$i];
         $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity')[$i];
         $price = $this->input->post('price')[$i];
         $discount =$this->input->post('discount')[$i];
         $amount = $this->input->post('amount')[$i];

         
             
        $data = array(
        
             'order_id'=> $order_id,
             'product_name'=>$product_name,
             'barcode'=> $barcode,
             'sm'=> $sm,
             'spl'=> $spl,
             'quantity'=>$quantity,
             'price'=>$price,
             'discount'=> $discount,
             'amount'=> $amount,
            
             
        
        );     
             
             $this->Sale_model->insert_sales_data($data);
             echo "Data inserted successfully!";    
               
             
             
             
             
         }
      }

      else 
      {
          redirect('login');
      }
        


       
      
        
    }
```

I am using Codeigniter .Please tell me how can i  the functionality that i mentioned above?

Comment: You are receiving values as array `$this->input->post('productname')[$i]`, but while sending you are not sending as array. I think below answer should help you. you should `serialize()` and pass to ajax.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I am getting blank response in the alert when i pass the whole form using serialize()  function to ajax..!!

Comment: can u update your javascript code?

Comment: I have edited my code please check..!!

Comment: Just do this, `data: $('#inventory_form').serialize()`. No need to again pass as data. Or else you have to change in php to access `data` index in `$this->input->post()`

Comment: Also in server side, use `print_r($_POST);` and see how the values are getting posted.

Comment: how can i access each field in my controller and save it to the database as you can see in the code of my controller?

Comment: see my above comment. Also in server side, use `print_r($_POST);` and see how the values are getting posted. It will print out the post array. U ll understand how to loop through that array.

Answer (score 0):

why are you getting single values in your ajax request?

```
var barcode = $('#barcode  option:selected').val();
var productname = $('#brcode_product').val();
var sm = $('#sm  option:selected').val();
var spl = $('#spl').val();
var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
var price = $('#price').val();
var discount = $('#discount').val();
var amount = $('#amount').val();
```

why not just serialize your form and then pass that serialize data?

Comment: well i want to pass and save this data one by one i know i am missing id somewhere but i am not getting how can i pass the increamented id to the ajax function.Could you please tell me how can i get value of each input and select tag along with the id and pass it to ajax function?

Comment: @PranaySute, if you pass the whole form to your back end, your backend/php code will have array of values.

Things you need to check:
1. Make sure that values of the form are passed in the backend(do print_r or var_dump to see the data passed by your request).
2. Another problem that I can see is that your ids are in array form(e.g. myid[1]) while you're accessing them in js by exact id(e.g. $('#myid').val()). This might be the cause of you getting single letters. Try to check the values that you're passing before doing the ajax request. try doing console.log and check the console result

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#save_btn').on('click', function () { var formdataString = $("#inventory_form"); $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost/retail/main/store", type: "POST", data: formdataString.serialize(), success: function (res) { alert(res); } }); });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.